# Understanding なぜかって

Tags: particle-と, quotes

Consider

> じゃあ なぜ落とした？
>
> 丁寧に使い方まで書いて 間違って落としたなんて言うなよ
>
> **なぜかって？**
>
> 退屈だったから

In this context, what does なぜかって mean? And is it parsed as

1. なぜ + かって, where かって is the て-form of some verb
2. なぜ + か particle + って？

Answer (score 3):

In your context, it's parsed as 2., i.e. って is the informal version of the quotative particle と. The implicit part that is ommited would be 言う/聞く/問う:

> なぜか　why?
>
> って[言う]？　you say

So the complete sentence would mean something along the lines:

> なぜかって[言う]　"why?", you say?

Note that **there are two questions in the expression**, the first one inside the quote なぜか, denoted by the particle か, and the second one is after de implicit 言う, denoted by the question mark "?".

Comment: なぜ means "why", but doesn't なぜか mean "somehow"? If so, why isn't this sentence なぜって instead of なぜかって? (Maybe you're answering this already with "Note that there are two questions in the expression...", but I'm not quite grokking it for some reason).

Comment: Yes, that's why I highlighted this part "there are two questions in the expression". In this case, なぜか is not "somehow" but a short for "なぜですか", if you want. So, imagine the clunky 「なぜですか」と言いますか. Or, paraphrasing in English, "Are you asking "Why?" ?" (Although in natural English we wouldn't add the first question mark, tbh)

Comment: Also, I am not a native speaker so take what I say with a grain of salt, but probably just なぜって？ would work too.